# How to invoke a java static method from jruby

Tags: java, jruby

How do I do this?

```
include Java
Thread.currentThread.sleep 3
```

I saw a posting from several years ago but it did not directly answer the question.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
Java::JavaLang::Thread::sleep 3
```

or

```
Java::JavaLang::Thread.sleep 3
```

(Note that the static call [sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) on Thread causes the current thread to sleep, so no need to call `currentThread()`, and that sleep time is in millisecond).

Here is an example (if you use JRuby prior to 1.7, you will need to add `require 'java'`):

```
t = Java::JavaLang::Thread.new do
  puts "Hi."
  Java::JavaLang::Thread::sleep 3000
  puts "Done."
end
t.start
```